# Can anyone show me why does it give me variable not initialized?

Tags: java, if-statement

Every time I try to compile this it shows me `d1` variable may not be initialized. I think problem may in the `else if`. Tell me how to run 2 statements in `else if`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class IDC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("                        ");
        System.out.println("Input ID card no...");

        String x = scan.next();


        x = x.substring(0, x.length() - 1); //removing the last char of the string

        String CardNo = x;

        String y = x = x.substring(0, x.length() - 7); //birthday

        y = "19" + y; //birth year = y




        String CardNO1 = CardNo.substring(0, CardNo.length() - 4);

        //System.out.println(CardNO1);

        CardNO1 = CardNO1.substring(2);

        //System.out.println(CardNO1);

        //gender

        int g = Integer.parseInt(CardNO1); //converting string to int
        String G;
        if (g < 500) {
            G = "Male";
        } else {
            G = "female";
        }
        //System.out.println(G);
        double C = Integer.parseInt(CardNO1);
        if (C > 500) {
            C = C - 500;
        } else {
            C = C;
        }
        //calculating month and the day of birth

        double d1;
        int Month;
        //

        if (C < 31) {
            Month = 1;
            d1 = C;
        } else if (C <= 60) {
            Month = 2;
            d1 = C - 31;
        } else if (C <= 91) {
            Month = 3;
            d1 = C - 60;
        } else if (C <= 121) {
            Month = 4;
            d1 = C - 91;
        } else if (C <= 152) {
            Month = 5;
            d1 = C - 121;
        } else if (C <= 182) {
            Month = 6;
            d1 = C - 152;
        } else if (C <= 213) {
            Month = 7;
            d1 = C - 182;
        } else if (C <= 244) {
            Month = 8;
            d1 = C - 213;
        } else if (C <= 274) {
            Month = 9;
            d1 = C - 244;
        } else if (C <= 305) {
            Month = 10;
            d1 = C - 274;
        } else if (C <= 335) {
            Month = 11;
            d1 = C - 305;
        } else if (C <= 366) {
            Month = 12;
            d1 = C - 335;
        } else {
            Month = 00;
        }
        //double d1;

        System.out.println("                        ");

        System.out.println("Your Birthday...  ");
        System.out.println("Date.." + d1);
        System.out.print("Month.. " + Month);
        System.out.println("  Year.. " + y);

        System.out.println("                        ");

        System.out.println("Your Gender...");
        System.out.println(G);

    }

}
```

Comment: What will happen when `C > 366`? you are not initializing `d1` in the `else` block

Comment: please provide neater code

Comment: Messy code hits for 100 points. You are dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d1 is not initialized in the else block and in only in the if or else if blocks, so if all the statements in if() and else if() blocks are false then the controller comes to the else block, where d1 is still not initialized. so when you try to access it inside system.out.println(), the compiler rightly throws the error. you may want to initialize the value to 0 in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you sir,It works ,I'm new to java still studying thank you again!